Cannot have more than one RequestParam in my RestController
I get a very basic error when trying to create a very basic Spring RestController. I must be missing something very basic here.
To reproduce:

Create a new Spring project with Spring Web here: https://start.spring.io/
Add the following Controller:


import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class WeirdErrorController {
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String tryIt(
        @RequestParam(value = "a") String a,
        @RequestParam(value = "b") String b
    ) {
        return ("Here are the args: " + a + ", " + b);
    }
}



Run it with ./gradlew bootRun.

Make a request:


curl http://localhost:8080/test?a=foo&b=bar

Get this error:
Required request parameter 'b' for method parameter type String is not present]

I am running this on Ubuntu 22.04 in WSL2 in Win 11.
I have tested this in multiple configurations with the same result. Tried both Java 17 and Java 21. Is this a WSL2 related bug?

Try to use an endpoint inside a quote curl "http://localhost:8080/test?a=foo&b=bar"

Yep, @Feelfree has it right - Bash is interpreting your command as curl http://localhost:8080/test?a=foo & b=bar, i.e. "please run curl http://localhost:8080/test?a=foo and b=bar simultaneously". This catches me out constantly.

Omg. Thanks! That did work! I was convinced curl wasn't the issue because I also tried using request.get in playwright at one point. I guess I messed something else up in that attempt.

As pointed out by @feel-free the issue was in my curl command. I need to quote my url:
curl "http://localhost:8080/test?a=foo&b=bar"


By default @RequestParam has a required flag that equals to true. You can make it optional using @RequestParam(required = false).
I recommend to look into details at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-param

Thanks but I want them both to be required. The issue was curl argument formatting.
